# Как в Contact Form 7 получить все mail-tags из определенной формы, например по id формы?

Tags: contact-form7

Нужно получить все mail-tags ([your-name], [your-email] и т.д.) из определенной формы.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:

```html
$contact_form = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_instance( $id );

foreach ( (array) $contact_form->collect_mail_tags() as $mail_tag ) {
    echo sprintf(
        '<span><strong>[%2$s]</strong></span> ',
        'mailtag code used',
        esc_html( $mail_tag ) );
}
```